# How to do the css to select options?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working in a project angular js and spring boot. I want to do this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEnba.jpg) to the  select option  in my project :

```
<div  class="">
        <select style="line-height: 40px;" ng-model="nameHotelSelected"  id="notIE"  placeholder=""  class="fa fa-search" ng-options="nameHotel.name for nameHotel in hotels  | orderBy :'name'" ng-change="changedValue(this)" >
                            <option   value="">link this contact to ...</option>    
                            <option style=" display: none;"  data-tokens="{{nameHotel.name}}">{{nameHotel.name}}</option>                   

                    </select> 
       </div>
```

my css:

```
<style>
.notIE.select {
    width: 150px;
    margin: 10px;
}
.notIE.select:focus {
    min-width: 150px;
    width: auto;
}  </style>
```

I try to add but the necessary css but  i didn't succeeded. any help thanks in advance:

Answer (score 0):

This

```
.notIE.select {
    width: 150px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

targets any element with **two** classes `.notIE` and `.select`

`notIE` is, in this case, an ID and is targeted with the "hash" `symbol`#`

SO all you will need is `#notIE` since there can only be one element with that ID on the page because IDs are *unique*.

It's also, perhaps, worth mentioning that `select`here is an **element** and so does not need the period `.` notation which applies to classes.

You *could* use `select#notIE` but as I mentioned above this would be redundant.